# Facebook Login Redirect Loop

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Hello there I am working on a website which has redirect loop

Here is the file the issue with facebook integration has issue...it redirects..

https://www.whyshopping.com/login.php?login=facebook

It contains the following code:

```
<?php

include_once( 'generic.class.php' );

class Jigowatt_integration extends Generic {

    public $enabledMethods;
    public static $socialLogin = array(
        'twitter',
        'facebook',
        'google',
        'yahoo'
    );

    private $result;
    private $num;

    function __construct() {

        $this->enabledMethods = $this->findEnabledMethods();

        /**
         * Twitter.
         */
        if (in_array('twitter', $this->enabledMethods)) {
            require 'integration/twitter/EpiCurl.php';
            require 'integration/twitter/EpiOAuth.php';
            require 'integration/twitter/EpiTwitter.php';
        }


        /**
         * Facebook.
         */
        if (in_array('facebook', $this->enabledMethods)) {
            require 'integration/facebook/facebook.php';
        }


        /**
         * OpenID Networks (Google, Yahoo).
         */
        if (in_array('google', $this->enabledMethods) || in_array('yahoo', $this->enabledMethods)) {
            include_once( 'integration/openid/openid.php' );
        }

        /** If the user is logged out, we'll treat them as a guest. */
        if (empty($_SESSION['jigowatt']['user_id'])) {
            //$this->guestLogin();
            return false;
        }

        $this->retrieveInfo();

        /** User wants to unlink his account from a social method. */
        if ( !empty($_GET['unlink']) ) {
            $this->unlink($_GET['unlink']);
            $this->retrieveInfo();
        }

        if ( !empty($_GET['link']) ) {
            $this->link_account($_GET['link']);
            $this->retrieveInfo();
        }

    }

    /** Check if this method is already in linked or not. */
    public function isUsed($method) {

        return !empty($this->result[$method]);

    }

    private function retrieveInfo() {

        $params = array( ':user_id' => $_SESSION['jigowatt']['user_id'] );
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `login_integration` WHERE `user_id` = :user_id;";
        $stmt = parent::query($sql, $params);

        $this->num = $stmt->rowCount();
        $this->result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    }

    private function findEnabledMethods() {

        $methods = array();

        foreach ( self::$socialLogin as $method )
            if ( parent::getOption('integration-'.$method.'-enable') )
                $methods[] = $method;

        return $methods;

    }

    public function link_account($link, $login = false) {

        /** Make sure we only allow specific social links. */
        if ( !in_array($link, self::$socialLogin) )
            return false;

        /** Check if user is already linked. */
        if ( !empty($this->result[$link]) ) {
            parent::displayMessage(sprintf('<div class="alert alert-warning">' . _('Your account is already linked with %s!') . '</div>', ucwords($link)), false);
            return false;
        }

        /** See if the link was successful. */
        if ( !empty($_SESSION['jigowatt'][$link]) ) {
            if (!$login) $this->connect($link);
            return false;
        }

        switch ($link) :

            case 'facebook' :
                    header( 'Location: ' . $this->facebook_url() );
                    exit();
                break;

            case 'twitter' :
                    header( 'Location: ' . $this->twitter_url() );
                    exit();
                break;

            default :
                    $this->openid_url($link);
                break;

        endswitch;

    }

    private function connect($link) {

        if ( empty($_SESSION['jigowatt']['user_id']) )
            return false;

        $params = array(
            ':user_id'      => $_SESSION['jigowatt']['user_id'],
            ':session_link' => $_SESSION['jigowatt'][$link]
        );

        if ($this->num < 1)
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `login_integration` (`user_id`, `$link`) VALUES (:user_id, :session_link);";
        else
            $sql = "UPDATE `login_integration` SET `$link` = :session_link WHERE `user_id` = :user_id;";

        parent::query($sql, $params);
        parent::displayMessage(sprintf('<div class="alert alert-success">%s</div>', _('Successfully linked with ' . ucwords($link))), false);

    }

    private function unlink($provider) {

        if ( !in_array($provider, self::$socialLogin) )
            return false;

        if ( empty($this->result[$provider]) ) {
            parent::displayMessage(sprintf('<div class="alert alert-warning">' . _('You are not yet linked with %s') . '</div>', ucwords($provider)), false);
            return false;
        }

        $params = array( ':user_id'  => $_SESSION['jigowatt']['user_id'] );
        $sql = "UPDATE `login_integration` SET $provider = null WHERE `user_id` = :user_id;";
        parent::query($sql, $params);

        unset($_SESSION['jigowatt'][$provider]);

        parent::displayMessage(sprintf('<div class="alert alert-success">' . _('Successfully unlinked from %s') . '</div>', ucwords($provider)), false);

    }

    private function openid_url($link) {

        $providers = array(
            'google' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/openIdConnect',
            'yahoo'  => 'https://me.yahoo.com',
            'aol'    => 'http://openid.aol.com/{username}',
            'openid' => ''
        );

        if ( !empty($_GET['link']) || !empty($_GET['login']) )
            $link = !empty($_GET['link']) ? $_GET['link'] : $_GET['login'];

        try {
            $openid = new LightOpenID(str_replace("www.","", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
            if(!$openid->mode) {
                if(!empty($link)) {

                    $openid->identity = $providers[$link];

                    $openid->returnUrl = str_replace("www.","", SITE_PATH) . basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '?link=' . $link;
                    $openid->required = array('contact/email', 'namePerson/first', 'namePerson/last');
                    header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
                    exit();
                }

            } elseif($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
                echo 'User has canceled authentication!';
            } else {

                if ($openid->validate()) :

                    if( !empty($providers[$link]) ) :

                        $_SESSION['jigowatt'][$link] = $openid->identity;
                        $this->connect($link);
                        $_SESSION['jigowatt']['openIDMisc'] = $openid->getAttributes();
                        $_SESSION['jigowatt']['openIDMisc']['type'] = $link;
                        $_SESSION['jigowatt']['openIDMisc'][$link] = $openid->identity;

                    endif;

                endif;

            }
        } catch(ErrorException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

    public function facebook_url() {

        if( !empty($_SESSION['jigowatt']['facebook']) )
            return false;

        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
          'appId'  => parent::getOption('facebook-app-id'),
          'secret' => parent::getOption('facebook-app-secret'),
        ));

        $this->fbUser = $facebook->getUser();

        if ($this->fbUser) :
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
          try {
            $_SESSION['jigowatt']['facebookMisc'] = $user_profile;
            $_SESSION['jigowatt']['facebook'] = $this->fbUser;
          } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
            $this->fbUser = null;
          }

        endif;

        $params = array(
          'redirect_uri' => str_replace("https://www.","", SITE_PATH) . basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '?link=facebook',
          'scope' => 'email'
        );

        return $this->fbUser ? '#' : $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);

    }

    public function twitter_url() {

        if ( !empty($_SESSION['jigowatt']['twitter']) )
            return false;

        $consumer_key    = parent::getOption('twitter-key');
        $consumer_secret = parent::getOption('twitter-secret');

        $this->twitterObj = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);

        if( !empty($_GET['oauth_token']) ) {

            $this->twitterObj->setToken($_GET['oauth_token']);
            $token = $this->twitterObj->getAccessToken();
            $this->twitterObj->setToken($token->oauth_token, $token->oauth_token_secret);
            $twitterInfo = $this->twitterObj->get_accountVerify_credentials();
            $twitterInfo = $twitterInfo->response;

            $_SESSION['jigowatt']['twitter'] = $twitterInfo['id'];
            $_SESSION['jigowatt']['twitterMisc']['username'] = $twitterInfo['screen_name'];
            $_SESSION['jigowatt']['twitterMisc']['id'] = $twitterInfo['id'];
            $_SESSION['jigowatt']['twitterMisc']['name'] = $twitterInfo['name'];

        }

        return !empty($_SESSION['jigowatt']['twitter']) ? '#' : $this->twitterObj->getAuthenticateUrl( null,array('oauth_callback' => str_replace("https://www.","", SITE_PATH) . basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '?link=twitter' ));

    }


}

$jigowatt_integration = new Jigowatt_integration();
```

Comment: No Answers Yet But Why?

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution actually my .htaccess file had the issue & it worked

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]`